# Joomla database Export Issue

Tags: mysql, joomla, mysql-error-1064, joomla2.5

When ever i export the DB & migrate the db to another host, while importing im getting mysql error each time. Particularly issue in in importing `Usergroup table`.

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
 to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9' at line 17
```

Comment: I got the Solution.....                                                   Export the database with "SQL compatibility mode" e.g. "MYSQL40"
and import the database with the same SQL compatibility mode "MYSQL40"

Comment: Add your solution as an answer, then select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Solution..... Export the database with "SQL compatibility mode" e.g. "MYSQL40" and import the database with the same SQL compatibility mode "MYSQL40"